# Why is selenium not getting any data from the website im trying to scrape

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

First off sorry if this is a duplicate to a similar question but here goes, I have been trying to scrape some `urls` listed on a web page with selenium I have tried `.find_elements_by_class_name()`, `.find_elements_by_tag_name()` and all others similar yet I always get back nothing here is my code:

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://hackerone.com/directory/programs?offers_bounties=true&asset_type=URL&order_direction=DESC&order_field=started_accepting_at")

def scanProgramme(programme):
  driver.find_element_by_link_text(programme).click()
  links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="break-word"]')
  allLinks = []
  for l in links:
    allLinks.append(l)
  driver.close()
  return allLinks
```

Here is where I call `scanProgramme`:

```
@bot.command(name="scanH1", description="Starts from the beginning of most recent HackerOne programme and searches through domains only for bugs(XSS only as of right now)")
async def scanH1(ctx, *, programme):
  if programme == "":
    totalLinks = scanAllProgrammes()
  else:
   links = scanProgramme(programme)
   await ctx.channel.send(links)
```

I have a suspicion that is has something to do with the way the page loads but I am quite new to scraping so I am sorry if this is hard to understand or a bit vague.

Comment: Can you show us where you're calling `scanProgramme`?

Comment: Even manual try on the web site is `Sorry, something has gone wrong`

Comment: @sphennings okay I've edited the the question

Answer (score 1):

i could get the element with:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='break-word']")
```

you then simply need to get the text with `l.text` in your loop to get the links for your list